# Dyalog APL hijack Windows Key and do not give it back (Fedora 32/Gnome, Free Licence, Kitty)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, x11, apl, dyalog

When launching Dyalog, it will directly map the Windows Key as the APL Symbol key. However when I leave Dyalog with `⎕OFF`, it will not return in the normal state of the keyboard. Most of my WM keybinding involves the Win key and I did not find any other solutions than reboot my computers.

Is it possible to override Dyalog APL Key so it will not automatically transform the Win Key in APL Key?

I was planning to use a `setxkbmap` command to have the control on that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `dyalog -nokbd` then the keyboard setup will be skipped. Of course, you'll then have to handle the keyboarding yourself (see [APL Wiki](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Typing_glyphs_on_Linux) for details).

Alternatively, you can create a little script which restores your keyboard when APL terminates, as follows:

```sh
OLDLAYOUT=$(setxkbmap -query | sed -n 's/^layout://p')
OLDVARIANT=$(setxkbmap -query | sed -n 's/^variant://p')
OLDOPTION=$(setxkbmap -query | sed -n 's/^options://p')
dyalog
OLDLAYOUT=$(echo $OLDLAYOUT | sed 's/^$/,/')
OLDVARIANT=$(echo $OLDVARIANT | sed 's/^$/,/')
setxkbmap -layout $OLDLAYOUT -variant $OLDVARIANT -option -option $OLDOPTION
```

Comment: I opted for aliasing `dyalog` to `dyalog -nokbd` and managing my keyboard on my own. Thanks for the insight aournd the `mapl' bash script ! Is there a place where to report those to Dyalog?

Comment: @notagoodidea You can always email support@dyalog.com